# How to Copy ALL InlineShapes from Word to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, image, ms-word, copy

I'm trying to copy all inline shapes from a word document to excel sheet.
The Word Document has multiple pages, with multiple tables with images in them.
The code I'm using is:

```
Sub imageExtract()

Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim shpCurr As InlineShape

Dim i As Long

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\01.docx")


For Each shpCurr In wrdDoc.InlineShapes
    shpCurr.Range.CopyAsPicture
    Sheet10.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial
    i = i + 1
Next shpCurr

End Sub
```

**Can someone explain to me why it is working for all the shapes in the first page of the Word document, and doesn't work for the shapes from another pages?**

> wrdDoc.InlineShapes.Count shows the real number of the shapes in the doc, so the loop is compleate

I've tried to cut and paste each shape to the first page before .CopyAsImage, with no sucsess.

I also tried to loop through each table and reference to the table's inline shapes ( "wrdDoc.tbl.InlineShapes"), with no sucsess.

If I manualy move a picture from (let's say) Page2 to Page1 and run the code again, this picture is copied.

Comment: I don't see where your code initializes the "I" variable, thus the first time through the routine it would have a value of 0, which I think Excel would have a problem with as a reference to a cell. Could the issue be as simple as that?

Comment: That's my mistake. Actually this is just shorten version of the code which I cuted. The real one has line i=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is not the initial setting of the variable i, as I have mentioned in my comment above, then maybe you should try this code because not all shapes in a Word document are necessarily InlineShapes. The definition of InlineShapes in Word is they reside on their own paragraph. The other possibility for Shapes in a Word document are they have wrapping text and are anchored to some other place in the document. The significance here for InlineShapes and Floating Shapes is they each have to be referenced separately.

Of course you have mentioned that the InlineShapes count matches to what you expect but ... who knows ... maybe try this:

```
    Sub imageExtract()
    
        Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
        Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
        Dim iShp As Word.InlineShape, shp As Word.Shape
        
        Dim i As Long
        
        Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\01.docx")
        
        If wrdDoc.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To wrdDoc.Shapes.Count
                Set shp = wrdDoc.Shapes(i)
                shp.ConvertToInlineShape
            Next
        End If
        If wrdDoc.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To wrdDoc.InlineShapes.Count
                Set iShp = wrdDoc.InlineShapes(i)
                iShp.Range.CopyAsPicture
                Sheet10.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial
            Next
        End If
    
    End Sub
```

UPDATE

After you sent me the files I was able to figure out that the problem is with Excel's PasteSpecial and if executed too many times an error 1004 PasteSpecial method of Range class failed because for some unknown reason something clears the clipboard and attempting to paste an empty clipboard generates the error.

I altered your code to use Word's Selection method to copy the images versus a Range method that was in your original code and that took care of the problem ... strange but it works. I also added some other code so that Word is properly closed out when the routine ends.

```
Sub imageExtract()
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim shpCurr As Word.InlineShape
    Dim i As Long
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\01.docx")
    i = 1
    wrdDoc.Activate
    Debug.Print wrdDoc.InlineShapes.Count
    
    'On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each shpCurr In wrdDoc.InlineShapes
        shpCurr.Select
        wrdApp.Selection.CopyAsPicture
        Sheet10.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
    'the following is copying only one character which will clear the clipboard
    'and prevent the message about wanting to save the last thing copied
    wrdApp.Selection.EndKey wdStory
    wrdApp.Selection.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
    wrdApp.Selection.Copy
    
    wrdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    wrdApp.Quit
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Complete"
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & Chr(32) & Err.Description, vbCritical
    wrdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    wrdApp.Quit
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your time spent. I run your code after some changes (set iShp = wrdDoc.InlineShapes(i)) and the result is ALMOST the same. First and second pictures (which are in the first page of the doc) are copy-pasted correctly and then on i=3 an error appears "Paste Special method of Range class failed". There is something deeper it seems.

Comment: Actually there are no floating shapes in the doc. All the shapes are InlineShapes. Each of them is placed in a merged table cell (including the ones in Page 1). I can easily select each one of them via VBA (wrdDoc,InlineShapes(i).Select). I also tried to select them before I copy them.

Comment: Have you tried an On Error Resume Next command? I'm wondering if you have a problem with shape 3 but others are okay. Also, paste commands will generate an error if nothing is on the clipboard, so maybe the copy is not really happening for that shape???

Comment: Yes I tried On Error Resume Next and it is the same for all the 47 shapes. If I move them all in Page 1 all of them are copied. " Also, paste commands will generate an error if nothing is on the clipboard, so maybe the copy is not really happening for that shape???" I don't know how to check if the Copy is happening, but it seems it is not.

Comment: If not proprietary and you want to send me the first 2 pages of the document, I'll take a look. Use Info@ and then my company domain name from my profile.